# Convex conjugate of sum of a convex function and an indicator

Tags: convex-analysis

Let $X$ be some topological vector space with dual $X^*$. Let $f$ be a proper convex function from $X$ to the extended reals, and let $1_C$  denote the indicator function for some convex set $C$.

Is there a nice general expression for $(f+1_C)^*$, the convex conjugate of $f+1_C$?

Comment: This can be expressed as the infimal convolution of $f^*$ the convex conjugate of $f$ with the support function of $C$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I agree, but is there any further simplification that's possible?

Comment: I don't know of any but I am also very interested if there are any!